# C++ array parameters inside function not being declared

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, display

I'm new to C++ so apologies if this is a stupid question. I'm trying to create a function that 3 arrays in its parameter. I'm getting the error that each one of them isn't being declared.

code in header:
    #ifndef ADDRESSMODEL
    #define ADDRESSMODEL
    #define ADDRESSDEBUG

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;
class PostCode
{
public:
     PostCode(void);
     ~PostCode();
     void postCodeCompare(tempPostCode[], theRoutingArray[], theIdentifier[]);

private:

    char theRoutingArray[4];
    char theIdentifier[5];
    char tempPostCode[8];
};

inline PostCode :: PostCode(void)
{
    strcpy( theRoutingArray, "000");
    strcpy( theIdentifier, "0000");
    cout << "Debug constructor called" << endl;
}

inline PostCode :: ~PostCode()
{
    cout<< "Destructor" << endl;
}

inline int PostCode :: postCodeCompare(tempPostCode, theRoutingArray, theIdentifier)
{
    char postCode[] = theRoutingArray + theIdentifier;
    if (postCode[0] == tempPostCode[0]){
        cout << 1 << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << 0 << endl;
    }
}



#endif
```

Code in main:
    #include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

```
int main( void){
cout << "main has started" << endl;

PostCode myCode;
char theRoutingArray[4];
char theIdentifier[5];
char tempPostCode[8];

cout << "Please type in your routing key: " << endl;
cin.getline(theRoutingArray, 4);

cout << "Please type in your identifier: " << endl;
cin.getline(theIdentifier, 5);

PostCode.postCodeCompare();

cout << "main has finished" << endl;


return 0;

}
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't properly declared inputs to your postCodeCompare method, which look like they are meant to just be your private members. Also are you sure you want pointer addition in that method? I advise you switch to `std::string` to get some clearer functionality and easier code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Advice:* read a good C++ book that explains the basics. [C++ Primer 5th edition](https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Primer-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113) is an example.

Your syntax for the array parameters is incorrect: you're missing the **type** of the array elements in the declaration, and you're missing both the element **type** and the *"array syntax"* in the definition.

Additionally, you have a return type mismatch between the definition and the declaration.

```
void postCodeCompare(char tempPostCode[], char theRoutingArray[], char theIdentifier[]);
```

...

```
inline int PostCode :: postCodeCompare(
    char tempPostCode[], char theRoutingArray[], char theIdentifier[]){ /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error "tempPostCode[] has not been declared".

Comment: You have a return type mismatch as well. `postCodeCompare` is declared as `void` and defined as `int`. Here's [**a working example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sUcitjYNU9HPZcuH). Please go read a C++ book!